# Is it possible model a perspective image in orthographic view

Tags: modeling

I am new to blender and I am not clear that is it possible to model a perspective image in orthographic view because I never succeeded whenever I tried but I could see tutorials put up modeling a perspective image in orthographic view. I am not sure whether the image is perspective or orthographic. This is the link to one of the video    http://youtu.be/86JiuZpbi_w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but ...
You have to keep in mind that using photographs as reference images you will always have a bit of "distortion". Therefore use them only as loose reference, not as "set-in-stone-rules".

If you start for example in the front-view, adding all the faces they will be completly flat, and if looked from any other angle, they will appear as a big plane without any structure. Now if you switch to side-view and start moving the verticies horizontal you'll get more and more "3d-ish".

(maybe somebody can add explaining images to this answer)

Comment: But it works when I model an orthographic image in orthographic view. What I did is just downloaded a free model and captured screenshot of all side of it in orthographic view and then I used it as a reference.

Comment: Ok I give up, from now I will never try to trace an image, instead I will use them as loose reference.