# How to set-up the perspective view based on a reference image?

Tags: 3d-view

How to set-up the perspective view based on a reference image, before starting to model what's on the image?

Comment: before starting to model what's on the image

Comment: You can edit your post, instead of adding a comment.

Comment: possibly related: [Is it possible model a perspective image in orthographic view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9095/is-it-possible-model-a-perspective-image-in-orthographic-view)

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative to background images (which can't be displayed in perspective), you could use an [*Image empty*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Empties) (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Empty > Image*).

Image empties can be rotated, scaled, and translated just like any other object.

You can make empties transparent by adjusting the *Transparency* slider in *Properties > Object data > Empty*:

[image]

Note that when using transparent image empties, they will not be correctly drawn when they are not selected if *Transparency* is unchecked in *Properties > Object > Display*:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View_Options) clearly states that this is currently not possible to setup a background image in perspective view:

> They are only available for Top, Side and Front (and their
>   complementary versions) orthographic views! The picture remains the
>   same when you switch between these six views.

But there is one exception, when you switch camera mode <kbd>NUMPAD-0</kbd> the background images will still be visible:

[image]