# How do I scale my reference images correctly within Blender and is there an easier way?

Tags: 3d-view, image

I am trying to model this car and I got the blueprints and cropped each of the views and check that they were all within the scale of each other. I used these blueprints here

http://carblueprints.info/blueprints/porsche/porsche-911-gt3-2.gif

I didn't have to resize any of them just crop it so that each view is their own file and saved them in png format. So when I placed them in Blender they got resized and I don't know how to scale them within Blender.

This is what I'm getting so far.
[image: blender with reference images loaded in 3D view]

The length of the car from the front is the same length as the car from the side view. I want to scale down the front view of the car but I do not know how. Also is there a way I can prevent blender from scaling so that when I import it, the images all stay in their respective sizes so I won't have to do any scaling in Blender.

Answer (score 13):

You are using background images.
The way you scale a background image is by adjusting the *Size* value. It is located at the bottom of the background image settings in the properties region (<kbd>N</kbd>) in the 3D view.
[image: background image settings]

---

However you may find it easier to use Image empties instead of the background images.
Question links:
[How to set-up the perspective view based on a reference image?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9328/2217)
[Drag background images in 3D view?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3339/2217)

[cgCookie tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20150315030831/http://cgcookie.com/blender/2015/03/11/setting-image-planes/) and an [older cgCookie tutorial](https://vimeo.com/25737480)

Comment: I would suggest using empties. They are scalable in the viewport and you can align them to each other without guessing (top line matches top line, bottom to bottom, etc.), which makes modeling overall a much more pleasant experience. Background images are ok, too, I just prefer empties.